# UPDATE after SELECTing certain records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my `customer` table, `ref` is the auto increment and `ID` is the customer identification number.  Hence there are multiple `ID` for each customer (which form a history of each customer).  I want to update the most recent record for each customer by setting the `likelihood` field to 1 in all cases - but without creating a new record.

I thought a query like this would do the job:

> UPDATE customer SET likelihood = 1 WHERE customer.ref IN
>   (SELECT MAX(ref) FROM customer GROUP BY ID)

but I get the following error:

> "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'customer' for update in FROM clause"

Where am I going wrong?

Edit:
Some sample data (not the complete table)

```
ref | ID | likelihood | name
----+----+------------+-----
  1 |  1 |          0 | a
  2 |  2 |          0 | b
  3 |  1 |          0 | a
  4 |  2 |          0 | b
  5 |  1 |          0 | a
  6 |  1 |          0 | a
```

So I want to pick out:

```
  4 |  2 |          0 | b
  6 |  1 |          0 | a
```

and change them to:

```
  4 |  2 |          1 | b
  6 |  1 |          1 | a
```

Comment: Can u post some sample data...

Comment: is that error you pasted accurate?  the error is referencing the table 'clients' when the query is on the table 'customer'.

Comment: @kclair right message, wrong table - edited, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot remember whether it will allow a self join in an update. Give this a try -

```
UPDATE customer c1
LEFT JOIN customer c2
    ON c1.ID = c2.ID
    AND c1.ref < c2.ref
SET c1.likelihood = 1
WHERE c2.ID IS NULL
```

**EDIT**  I have changed the column used in the second join condition from ID to ref.

Comment: Thanks, a `JOIN` looks like the answer but that query changes every `likelihood` that isn't 1 to 1.

Comment: My apologies. I am not sure how I ended up using the ID instead of the ref in the second condition of the join.  It should work now.

Comment: This work perfectly, many thanks for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you cannot update the table that you are selecting from.  The where clause you are writing is selecting from the customers table, so you can't write to it in the update

You will probably need two queries to pull this off such as the following:

```
SELECT @max_ref:=max(ref) FROM customers;
UPDATE customers SET likelihood=1 WHERE ref=@max_ref
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's returned "# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

Comment: And I don't see how it'll know to pick the latest ID for each customer?

Comment: oh sorry I missed the part where it has to update EVERY customer

Comment: Also the query doesn't really do what you need it do, my fault for not reading the question thoroughly

Comment: Whilst I really appreciate jchong's help, as jchong has also said, this doesn't do what's required - so I'm not sure why it has been upvoted?